# Handling audio on Parse.com

Tags: ios, audio, parse-platform

Handling audio file on Parse.com.
Is it better to use PFFile? Or is there a way include audio data in a PFObject?

And if PFFile is the way to go. Is there a way to see the uploaded file in the Parse web console. Like on can see uploaded PFObjects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `PFFile` is the right choice and you can see the the uploaded files on console and by clicking on that file it will download that file and then you can check.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not quite following. Probably something wrong on the way I do. Yo write "PFFile is the right choice", but in your picture I see a list of PFObjects with a column of audio-data. What kind of code do you use to add a row to this list? Things may become clear when I see the code.

Comment: After some more experiment, I found out how you do. I was doing it wrong, not making the proper relation between the use of PFObject and PFFile.
No need for the code anymore.

Comment: That's great.. I was about to search the google for that. It's basically available in the parse tutorial. And I uploaded this mp3 file using parse console ofcourse you can do it via code :)